# negative lookbehind not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

I have strings of this form:

```
FPLBX(2x3)ZE(53x13)(4x7)ZGQO
```

I want to find the blocks in parenthesis but only when they're not preceded by another group.

The other way around works perfectly fine but I can't make it work with preceding.

current regex:

```
(\(\d*x\d*\))(?<!\))
```

Comment: Do yo mean `(?<!\))\([^)]*?\)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to put the so-called *negative lookbehind assertion*, i.e. the `(?<!\))`-part, *in front* of your search re:

```py
>>> import re
>>> txt = "FPLBX(2x3)ZE(53x13)(4x7)ZGQO"
>>> re.findall(r"(?<!\))(\(\d*x\d*\))", txt)
['(2x3)', '(53x13)']
```

Comment: I thought it was a condition you append to a block, not that you have to basically treat it like a character. Thank you.